# Mean ergodic theorem different assumption

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

> Show that the mean ergodic theorem still holds if we replace the assumption that $T$ is an isometry by the assumption that $T$ is contraction, that is $||T f|| ≤ ||f||$ for all $f ∈ H$ where $H$ is Hilbert space?

Why the theorem still holds? what is the relation between isometry  and contraction?
And how to show that $T $ is contraction iff $T ^∗ $ (adjoint operator of $T$) is a contraction?

Any help please.

Thanks.

Comment: What proof of the mean ergodic theorem do you know? Some proofs are easier to modify in this way than others.

Comment: Stein's proof in REAL ANALYSIS ,MEASURE THEORY, INTEGRATION AND HILBERT SPACE book (pages 294-296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew I remembered this problem. I have it saved on my computer from *exactly* 4 years ago!

Chapter 6 Exercise 25: Note that all we needed for the proof of the mean ergodic Theorem was to write $f= f_0+f_1$ for $f_0 \in S$ and $f_1 \in \overline{S_1}$. If $T$ is a contraction instead of an isometry, $A_nf_0$ is still equal to $f_0 = P(f)$ and $||A_n(f_1-f_1')|| \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ||T^k(f_1-f_1')|| \le ||f_1-f_1'||$. Thus, all we need to show is $S^\perp \subseteq \overline{S_1}$. It thus suffices to show $\overline{S_1}^\perp \subseteq S$. Observe that $f \in \overline{S_1}^\perp$ iff $\langle f,g-TG \rangle = 0$ $\forall g \in H \iff f = T^*f \iff f \in S_*$. Therefore, it suffices to show if $T$ is a contraction, then $S_* \subseteq S$.

\vspace{2mm}

Suppose $T^*f = f$. Then, $||Tf||\cdot||f|| \le ||f||^2 = \langle f, f \rangle = \langle f,T^*f \rangle = \langle Tf,f\rangle$ so we have equality in Cauchy-Schwarz implying $Tf = cf$ for some $c$. Then, $c\langle f,f\rangle = \langle cf,f \rangle = \langle Tf,f\rangle = \langle f,T^*f \rangle = \langle f,f\rangle \implies c = 1$, as desired.

Comment: Should we prove that $\overline{S_1}^\perp = S$ ?

Comment: in order to write $f =f_{0}+f_{1}$??

Comment: Don't you mean $S^\perp = \overline{S_1}$? I think you mean that. And, I think the inclusion $\overline{S_1} \subseteq S^\perp$ is obvious, which is why I said "all we need to show is $S^\perp \subseteq \overline{S_1}$".

Comment: And why this inclusion holds? do we need contraction assumption? in case of isometry operator it's holds.

Comment: Let $f \in \overline{S_1}$ so $f=g-Tg$ for some $g\in H$...now $<h,g-Tg>=<h,g>-<Th,Tg>$ where $h \in S$....then how can i conclude that this inner product is $ 0$. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @ks1 okay, I said in my previous comment "I think the inclusion $\overline{S_1} \subseteq S^\perp$ is obvious" just because I was guessing what I meant. Now I had the time to read through the argument. Here is what's going on. You can write any $f$ as $f_0+f_1$ for $f_0 \in S$ and $f_1 \in S^\perp$; this is basic Hilbert space stuff. As I said in my answer, all that was needed for the proof of the mean ergodic theorem was to write $f = f_0+f_1$ for $f_0 \in S$ and $f_1 \in \overline{S_1}$. So clearly it just suffices to show $S^\perp \subseteq \overline{S_1}$.

Comment: So no need to prove the reverse inclusion...but i want to ask you there was a hint in the book " $T $ is contraction iff $T ^∗ $ (adjoint operator of $T$) is a contraction"....do you think it will help in proving reverse inclusion??

Comment: What's the point of the hint?

Comment: idk, if u really want, ill go back to the book and think about it

Comment: If you can please...that will help me.

Comment: @ks1 is this a homework assignment? I can't help with that directly

Comment: I'm preparing for my exam...it is one of the suggestion problems

Comment: @ks1 I think the hint is applied in the last part of my answer

Comment: I think you used T is contraction...but no use for the adjoint operator!

Comment: Hi...could you help me in this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665617/l-px-separable-if-x-mu-is-separable-measure-space ?? @mathworker21

Comment: To prove $S\subseteq S_*$, we simply use the hint that $T$ is a contraction if and only if $T_∗$ is a contraction. This is an immediate consequence of Lemma 5.1 in Chapter 4.