# $L_p(X)$ separable if $(X,\mu)$ is separable measure space.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A measure space $(X,\mu)$ is separable if there is a countable family of measurable subsets $\{E_k \}_{k=1}^\infty $ so that if $E$ is any measurable set of finite measure , then $$\mu(E \triangle E_{n_k}) \to 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,as \,k\to0$$ for an appropriate subsequence $\{n_k \}$ which depends on $E$ .

> Prove that if the measure space $X$ is separable, then $L_{p}$ is separable when $1 ≤ p < ∞$.

I try to prove it like this:

We have for every measurable set $E$ with finite measure associated measurable set  $E_{nk}$ s.t. $\mu(E \triangle E_{n_k})<\epsilon$.

> > CLAIM: The collection$$ F:= \{\sum_{i=1}^Nr\chi_{E_{n_{i}}
> > }\}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, r\in Q  $$ is countable dense in $L^p$.

Since simple functions are dense in $L^p$ given $f \in L^p$, Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\phi$ such that $\|\phi-f\|_{L^p} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now, let $$\phi = \sum_{i=1}^{N} c_i \chi_{E_i}$$ with $E_i$ pairwise disjoint meaurable with finite measure. Let $\psi \in F$ with $$\psi = \sum_{i=1}^{N} r_i \chi_{E_{n_i}}$$  be such that $\mu(E_n \triangle E_{n_i})  < {\epsilon^p}$ with the $E_{n_i}$ pairwise disjoint. Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \int_\mathbb{X} |\phi-\psi|^p \, d\mu \right)^\frac{1}{p} &\leq& \left( \int_\mathbb{X} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}|c_i\chi_{E_i}-r_i\chi_{E_{n_i}}| \right)^p \, d\mu  \right)^\frac{1}{p} \\
& \stackrel{Minkowski}{\leq}& \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \int_\mathbb{X} |c_i\chi_{E_i}-r_i\chi_{E_{n_i}}|^p \, d\mu \right)^\frac{1}{p} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

I got stuck..!! I try to connect the last above inequality with symmetric difference between $E_n$ and $E_{n_i}$ but I have difficulties in that because of existences of $r_i$ and $c_i$.

I need help to complete the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) in first centered thing, $k \to 0$ should be $k \to \infty$. (2) in the CLAIM, you sum over $i$ but there's no $i$.

Comment: From Stein Analysis book k goes to 0...second one typo error

Comment: i don't see how $k$ could possibly be going to $0$. that makes absolutely no sense

Comment: also, the collection you defined in CLAIM is for a particular $E$? that seems wrong

Comment: my family contains all associated $E_{n_k}$ for each measurable set $E$

Comment: maybe I should write that $E_{n_{k}}$ belongs to the family of all associated measurable sets?

Comment: can i just posted an answer to the question and ignore your attempt

Comment: I'm not sure, k→0 means that to approximate $E$ by one set!

Comment: Off course you can...I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim that $\mathcal{A} := \{\sum_{i=1}^N r_i \chi_{E_{k_i}} : r_i \in \mathbb{Q}, k_1,\dots,k_N \ge 1\}$ is dense in $L^p$. Since simple functions are dense, it suffices to show simple functions are in the closure of $\mathcal{A}$. By linearity and the density of the rationals in the reals, it suffices to show that $\chi_E$ is in the closure of $\mathcal{A}$ for any measurable set $E$. So fix a measurable set $E$, and take $\epsilon > 0$. By assumption, there is some $E_k$ so that $\mu(E\Delta E_k) < \epsilon$. Then $||\chi_E - \chi_{E_k}||_p \le \epsilon^{1/p}$.

Comment: I tried to give a detailed answer for the question...So it's enough to show that $χ_E$ is in the closure of $A$

Comment: what did you mean about the closure...and isn't my family $F$ like the family $A$?

Comment: what do u think "dense" means?

Comment: Any element can be written as a linear combination of the dense set elements

Comment: i think you might not have the prerequisites for this book

Comment: So what you're definition of "dense"?

Comment: Just one question...I tried to show that $R^n$ with standard Lebesgue measure is separable measure space according to the definition in the beginning of my question....Do you know how to prove it?

Comment: @ks1 finite union of balls with rational radius